# designing custom UI for a local notification

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I'm in the process of designing a custom UI for local notifications in my App.

According to the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/platform/user-notifications/advanced-user-notifications?tabs=windows#designing-the-custom-ui), I need to expose to C# code the controls I've added to the storyboard.
Unfortunately, nothing is explained in that sense in the document.

What is the proper way to do it?

Any help appreciated.

**EDIT 1**:

I have found out that I need to [create an Outlet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/user-interface/ios-ui/creating-ui-objects?tabs=macos#using-xcode-interface-builder) for each control on the design surface, but there is no header file where to drag the controls to...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is neither header file nor code file **if you do not create the extension project at the same level of the iOS project**. I will open a bug with the VS for Mac Team.

My problem is solved by removing the old project that was in folder below the iOS project, then create it again at the same level. I remember that the project has not been added as a reference to the iOS project...

Answer (score 0):

If you are adding controls to the storyboard you created yourself, you need to create a UIViewController file, in XCode -> **new file** -> **Cocoa Touch Class** -> **Subclass of(select UIViewController)** , then click your storyboard and click the upper **left of the View Controller** changes the **Custom Class** name to the created UIViewController, and finally selects the control in the storyboard, holds **down the control**, clicks the mouse and drags a line, and drags it into the UIViewController and the code is automatically generated.

If it is in MainStoryboard, you can directly drag the control to ViewController, because MainStoryboard is bound to ViewController by default.

For more For details, you can check the documentation: [Storyboards in Xamarin.iOS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/user-interface/storyboards/indepth-storyboard?tabs=windows)

[image]

Comment: I'm not creating a storyboard myself. It is created automatically when selecting the Notification Content Extension project type in Visual Studio for Mac.

Comment: Click your storyboard in XCode, there will be three clickable controls above the storyboard, click the View Controller on the left to see if the Custom Class is bound to the ViewController.

Comment: I've dragged a progress bar to the storyboard, but it is not bound to a control in the c# code.

Comment: @OlivierMATROT, I updated a screenshot, you can refer to it

Comment: You seem to be working with an Xcode project which allows you to open both the storyboard and the header file. I have no such Xcode project. The UI Extension assistant does not create it.

Comment: @OlivierMATROT You need to open your VS project on your Mac, right-click the storyboard file **Open with** -> **XCode Interface Builder**, so that your project can be opened in XCode.

Comment: I can open the storyboard in XCode. But how can I make sure that code is generated in the c# file for each controls I add to the user interface?

Comment: When you use XCode to open the storyboard, drag the control to ViewController according to the method in the answer, you can go back to VS to view the code of the corresponding control in the corresponding ViewController.designer.cs file, you are in the .cs file It can be used directly.

Comment: Once again, there is no Objective C .h file when you open the storyboard with XCode. In the sample you show, there is an XCode project opened in XCode. In my case, there is no Xcode project, only the storyboard file. Please create a new notification content extension by using the wizard in Visual Studio for Mac to see what I mean by yourself. Open the storyboard in XCode and tell we where to drag the controls you've added to the storyboard surface.

Comment: You are designing in an extension and not in a xamrin.ios program, right?

Comment: I'm trying to design a custom UI for local notifications to be used in a Xamarin iOS app. This is done through a notification content extension per the documentation. Thanks for trying to help me.

Comment: Similarly, I created a Xamarin.ios program, added the Notification Content Extension, and included a storyboard and a NotificationViewController in the Extension. After opening the storyboard with XCode, there will be .h and .m files corresponding to NotificationViewController in XCode. Did you create the Extension like this?

Comment: When I created the notification content extension, the storyboard and notificationviewcontroller were already there in the extension project.

Comment: Yes, you click storyboard Open with -> XCode Interface Builder in this extension to open for design. The .h file will also be in XCode, then you can drag the controls into the .h file as I said above .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252398/discussion-between-olivier-matrot-and-dongzhi-wang-msft).